# DataDog group spans

Tags: c#, .net, metrics, datadog

We have a `.net` application, which runs on Qa-server, Staging-server and Prod-Server. Each server has `DataDogAgent` which sends metrics to DataDog. For Qa and Staging spans are stacked into stacktraces correctly:

[image]

But for Production server DataDog doens't group spans, instead of kinda 'stackTrace' i see scattered spans:

[image]

How to group together into 'stacktrace' spans in DataDog ?